# Can a planet with chaotic rotation have more than one ring rotating in differents axis?

Tags: planets, universe, explosions, planetary-rings

Let's say that planet earth have a big explosion . An explosion generated in earth big enough to change the planet shape. Making earth having a chaotic rotation like [Hyperion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_(moon))  leaving water and rocks forming rings. Could be possible for earth to have more than one ring rotation in different axis?

More info:

- Earth still orbiting the sun.

[image]

Thanks.

Edited since other questions don't answer my question.

Comment: Hard to say. But what I'd like to know is does the catacalysmic planet in question maintain the same rotation and orbit around the sun? Did it change? Because that might help determine if such a phenomenon can occur.

Comment: Per [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/107161/51094) Earth can't support even one ring long-term, let alone two at different angles. Pieces of the ring would impact each other, leading to bits of ring raining down on your surface periodically.

Comment: @Cadence The latter issue might be resolved by having rings at different distances from the Earth.

Comment: @CortAmmon It's not that the two rings would hit each other - each ring is composed of countless particles, and they orbit at slightly different speeds and inclinations. They run into each other all the time, even in a single planar ring.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Multi-planar planetary rings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10505/6986)

Comment: There is no such thing as "chaotic rotation." The vector of each pebble determines it's orbit. Those with inadequate velocity fall back to Earth. Those that exceeds escape velocity leave Earth's gravity well. The rest collide and perturb until a reasonably stable system is achieved.

Comment: @AustinTrigloff yes still orbiting the sun.

Comment: @user535733 how about Hyperion (moon of Saturn)?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you define rings.

If you want rings like Saturn's, then unfortunately no, those beautiful wide and bright rings are held in place by its own gravity and the gravity of its various moons, all of which rotate around basically the same axis. Any additional rings would need other moons orbit on a different axis to generate and sustain them.

As for different axis... it gets very very complicated very quickly, i'd recommend looking at the Astronomy.SE question [Could a cross-ringed planet exist](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16536/could-a-cross-ringed-planet-exist?rq=1) for more information.

Very narrow rings on different axis are possible but short lived, all you have to do is look at the amount of debris orbiting earth to see that a fair amount of it orbits in vastly different axes. But it would take tens of thousands of years for those debris fields to form rings, very narrow ones at that, and by then they would likely have de-orbited and burnt up in the atmosphere. But for a short time it would have formed a couple of very thin rings.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**
did you played 'beyblade' at some point of your life? or sth similar?
the gyroscope held itself up because of its centrifugalforce.
When you tryied to rotate a normal ball, the ball quickly loses the axis and spins wildly (if it has hit the ground), because it wasn't made for spinning straight.
That should solve the question if its possible.
**How** you do it is rather hard without smashing and destructing the hole planet.
You could let a giant meteor strike a pole with so much force, that the earth gets another spin. That means a giant inferno would kill everything on earth, even heavier than 65 Mio years ago. And it would maybe smash earth into pieces.
I trust you to find a better way :)
Maybe sth so magnetic that it moves a pole?
I hope this helps :)

Comment: I add more info to the question